# Scraping iterative data: empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning how to iterate scraping values from a webpage, I've used `bs4` before but I can't figure out why, even if this is a simple example, I'm getting an empty list (or element).

The test I would like to print/save is:

`<div data-v-1931433b="" class="mar-m c-r"> 9.1516 </div>`

The code I've used is:

```
 1 import json
 2 import requests
 3 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 4
 5
 6 url = 'https://goldencoreex.com/trade/index.html?spAsseType=0#/index'
 7
 8 html_page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
 9 elements = html_page.find_all("div", class_="mar-m c-r")
10
11 print(elements)
```

Only guess I have for this issue is that I may have messed-up with the url.

I would be also really much appreciate some hints on how to make the code run continuously, so to capture data whenever the element is updated.

Comment: page is dynamic, rendered through javascript. You'll need to look to see if the data is requested through API or use Selenium to allow the page to render before grabbing the html source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the page is rendered dynamically by `JS`, but you can query the `API` to get the data.

For example:

```
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

api_url = "https://www.goldencoreex.com/wap/api/realtime!execute.action?symbol=btc,bts,nkn,etc,gdq,xrp,eth,ltc,akro,qtum,bhd"
response = requests.get(api_url).json()

table = [[item['name'], item['open'], item['change_ratio']] for item in response["data"]]
print(tabulate(table, headers=["Name", "Open", "Change"], tablefmt="pretty"))
```

Output:

```
+-----------+----------+--------+
|   Name    |   Open   | Change |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| BTC/USDT  | 17809.35 | -5.88  |
| BTS/USDT  |  0.0232  | -6.03  |
| NKN/USDT  | 0.019426 | -3.58  |
| ETC/USDT  |  6.2325  | -4.51  |
| GDQ/USDT  |  9.2947  | -1.34  |
| XRP/USDT  |  0.5456  | -2.38  |
| ETH/USDT  |  527.37  | -3.79  |
| LTC/USDT  |  77.23   | -11.9  |
| AKRO/USDT | 0.00913  | -8.54  |
| QTUM/USDT |  2.6376  | -6.06  |
| BHD/USDT  |  2.5054  | -2.16  |
+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Hey how did you find this API? Does this look like a legitimate crypto exchange to you?

Comment: @Leafyshark I know almost nothing about crypto so I can't answer your question. As for the API endpoint, I've found it by tracking my browser's traffic. It comes in one of the requests. Check Developer Tool -> Network ->XHR.

Comment: @Leafyshark hi, I believe its 100% a scam crypto webpage rather than illegal. I found it randomly somewhere in a forum. Definitly DON'T put any money on crypto exchange web-pages, in general. Definitely not in that one, in particular. :)

Comment: Thanks, haha! But aren't you working on the site?